# Figure out which port a local Apache Spark UI is on

Tags: apache-spark

To find out some info about a local spark process, launched locally via `spark-shell` command I can do:

```
jps -lm | grep -i spark
```

However, how do I find what TCP port the UI is published on?

I have tried:

```
lsof -p PID
```

but no luck.

Comment: What spark component? Master? Driver? Worker? And how is it being launched (if driver)?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele just a spark shell launch. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you list open ports, you can filter by greping the PID (My pid is `30688`, but you can also grep by `java` or something just to narrow the results):

```
$ ss -l -p -n | grep -i 30688
```

And, unless you've reconfigured it to a dramatically different range, you should be able to see a 40* port (I replaced tabs with `--` to save space):

```
tcp--LISTEN--0--50--*:4040--*:*--users:(("java",pid=30688,fd=275))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you already have the PID. in that case you can run below, which should indicate what ports the process is listening on:

```
netstat -tunlp|grep LISTEN|grep PID
```

The spark driver process may be listening on more than one ports, so you may have to try http://host:port for the ports obtained.

Alternatively, if you are finding only one PIDs from your `jps | grep`, then you can be sure that the port is 4040(default spark web ui port), unless you find the args `spark.webui.port`. In  the latter case, get the port from the args value.